# monitor no hdmi signal

Tags: hdmi, monitor

I've installed ubuntu classic server 16.04 (Rasberry Pi 3 edition) found here https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/ on Rasbperry Pi 3 b and I'm able to ssh into it. I would like to use a desktop "stylish" setup for configuring the network and security settings. All I need is a bash shell to show up on monitor at boot.

After connecting the monitor and powering up the raspy this message shows up on the monitor:

```
Net:    Net Initialization Skipped
No ethernet found.
USB0:    Core Release: 2.80a
scanning bus 0 for devices…
```

What does it mean? I get a little square icon with rainbow colors in the right upper corner.

I have uncommented the the following lines in config.txt:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=1
config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_safe=1 ← the last thing I tried
```

I've also tried config_hdmi_boost=9

I'm using a mobile charger with an output of 5 V and 2.1 A to power up the raspy, but I'm not sure if it's sufficient enough if you want the raspy to display an image on the monitor.

This site https://howtoraspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-hdmi-not-working/ recommended a charger with an output of 5 V and 3 A.

I've asked the same question on Raspberry Pi forums, but they couldn't
help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So without monitor RPI boots up and network works fine, You able to ssh to RPI. With HDMI connected RPI unable to boot up. It looks like it's power supply issue. If You have multi-meter, check voltage, if it drops lower then 4.9V, just change power supply.

Did You connect something else to USB ports except keyboard and mouse? If yes, for example USB Hard Drive without external power supply, then it's definitely power supply issue. My RPI2 runs with two HDD, but!  I used soldering-iron and made my own USB cables. Power +5V and Ground goes to HDD and RPI with separate wires from Power supply. HDD and RPI only conneted with data+ data- and Ground (USB pinout). I bought 5A Power Supply just because my RPI runs 24for7 and I want to keep it cool and safe. Perhaps 3A should be enough to.

Comment: I've made some progress.  I get a login screen when keyboard is not connected.  Once the login screen comes up I connect the keyboard and login, really weird. I'll borrow a multi-meter from school and check the voltage.